# leetcode problem, why is [ ] not the same as [0] in int array

Tags: java, arrays

i am trying to return an empty array of size 0.
I do it this way,

return new int[0];

they say my output is [ ] and expected output should be [0],

I dont really see the difference, could someone please explain or show how to return correctly?

Comment: `return new int[1];` or `return new int[] {0};` (you are returning `[]`).

Comment: No it should't? `new int[0]` is a new int array, of length 0, which is `[]`. So that's doing exactly what you told it to do. However, if the output needs to be `[0]`, then that's not an array of length 0, but an array of length 1, with the int value `0` as first and only element.

Comment: If you are trying to return an empty array of size 0 as you stated, `new int[0]` sounds correct, but maybe you are reading the requirements incorrectly.

Answer (score 6):

`new int[0]` means an empty array - that is, an array with zero elements.  And because there are no elements, you see  `[]` when you print it out.

If you want to see `[0]` in the output - well that's an array with one element, and the value of that element is 0.  One way to initialise this would be `new int[] { 0 }`.